# using Facebook android SDK to login to custom server

Tags: android, facebook, security, authentication

Is it possible to use the Facebook Android SDK to login to generate a user custom key and then log into my custom serve.

Here is the scenario:
I have an android application, and a server that runs a recommendation engine based off user input.
I want the user to log into Facebook the first time the application runs, then never log in again.
From the facebook info I want to be able to pass something to my server that allows for a secure login.

if this is possible can you link an example.

I have scene stuff about OAuth and other things that you can do with the